# I'm noticing a decrease on List of X and game-recommendation questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Anybody else noticed it or is it just me being hopeful? Are we succeeding in steering the site into pure Q&A?

If so, this would be faster than I had hoped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Earning "Taxonomist" for [game-rec] really doesn't indicate to me that we're experiencing a decrease.

- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/are-there-any-similar-games-to-sim-tower - asked 2 hours ago
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/are-there-any-modern-games-similar-to-space-crusade asked 3 hours ago
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2752/pc-voice-chat-software - asked 9 hours ago
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/looking-for-a-multiplayer-game-with-large-teams-and-low-lag-sensitivity - asked 15 hours ago
- https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/any-good-mods-for-the-original-fallout-2-game - asked 19 hours ago

That's 5 in the span of 24 hours. 5/34 questions for that specific period of time.

If we go by average statistics, at 832 questions over 11 days, we have an average of 75 questions. Comparatively, for gaming recommendations alone we have 50 questions that are actually tagged with it (and several others which aren't), which we'll just use 5 as an average when you take error into account. Which is 7% of our average daily questions.

Note that I'm not discriminating here between questions that are broad lists and ones that are narrow.

Comment: Sadly I was mistaken, what I see is a low meta participation (this question has 6 views only so far)

Comment: @Juan See the comment exchange at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/self-imposed-restrictions - this seems to be proof of how our site is starting to look like just a collection of discussion polls.

Comment: I commented also, we just need to be strict in the hopes that with time people will adapt... if not, at least we can say we tried

Comment: I try to direct people to the FAQ for them to see the diagram of what this site is about, like my comment here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/games-like-arcanum

Answer (score 0):

That depends really on what you mean by decreased. There simply is a finite amount of list questions that can be asked and I think that so far we've had most of them, but there are still at least a few daily. We're probably going to be dealing with these questions at least until they're prominent in our FAQ and we have a List of X/Poll close reason.

Comment: oh, I disagree with this: "There simply is a finite amount of list questions that can be asked"

Comment: The number of list questions is about as finite as the number of non-list questions. The different permutations possible are available on so many different levels (genre, presence or absence of a feature, costume design, audience age, similarity to another game, play time, complexity, and hundreds of other arbitrary criteria before we even get into what the list is actually of) that we aren't going to just "run out" of these over time.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Of course, there's going to be a lot of 'possible' questions, but most of them so far have been very generic 'best open-source game' etc. Those kind of questions are going to run out. What we're then left with are specific questions which might not need be closed.